# Async to wait for a key in F#?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I would like to block async execution until the users presses any key in the console.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
let waitForAnyKey = async {
  do!
    new Task (fun () ->
      printfn "%s" "waiting for a key"
      Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
      printfn "%s" "got a key"
    )
    |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Used like this:

```
async {
  printfn "%s" "Press any key... "
  do! waitForAnyKey
  printfn "%s" "You pressed a key. "
}
```

However, the `Task` is never run.

- How should I write this in F#?
- Can I avoid creating a `Task` for this entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Without tasks, with `Async.FromContinuations`

```ml
open System

let waitForAnyKey =
    Async.FromContinuations (fun (cont, _, _) ->
        printfn "%s" "waiting for a key"
        cont (Console.ReadKey ())
        printfn "%s" "got a key"
    )

let test () =
    async {
        let! key = waitForAnyKey
        printfn "%O" key.Key
    }
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

test ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `waitForAnyKey` without the Task<->Async interop bits:

```ml
let waitForAnyKey = async {
  do Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
}
```

You can then call it any time you'd like to wait for input.  Your usage example would work just fine with this implementation.

Comment: What are the implications in terms of blocking child asyncs with this approach?

Comment: @sdgfsdh can you explain more your concern, I think this answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `Task` constructor creates a new Task but does not start it. Using [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) instead should fix the problem:

```
let waitForAnyKey = async {
  do!
    Task.Run (fun () ->
      printfn "%s" "waiting for a key"
      Console.ReadKey () |> ignore
      printfn "%s" "got a key"
    )
    |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Console.ReadKey does not currently have an equivalent that returns a Task (which surprised me), although the idea [has been suggested.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25036)